# Cling film wrapping two pieces of luggage together (on Wizzair)

Tags: luggage, tips-and-tricks, wizz-air

Somewhat often I encounter flights where 2 pieces of 'normal weight' luggage cost more than 1 piece of 'heavier' luggage. Me and my wife are traveling each with luggage of around 10-13kg, and as I was looking at a flight connection with two sequential WizzAir flights I noticed that once again 2 flights * 2 pieces of luggage of 20kg (€31) = 121 euros, vs 2 flights * 1 piece of luggage of 26kg (€39) = 79 euros. Point in case, it's a decent difference. So I wondered whether anybody knows whether tying them together and then cling wrapping them together (or putting them in an oversized heavy duty trash bag) as a single piece of luggage (easily staying under the maximum size limits) would have any realistic chance of getting us in trouble?

I mean, 40 euros might actually not be worth the trouble for us realistically speaking (layover would be decently long, so we would have to do it twice)... but I just had to wonder whether anybody had done this and/or had information about whether it's allowed?

Comment: I'd be wary of them falling off from each-other and then either getting lost

Comment: And how much will just buying a bigger suitcase cost?

Comment: @PeterM We're travelling long term with the same two backpacks, so the size, shape and weight are very much defined by what we can carry easily :)

Comment: Some airlines explicitly deny this. Remember that security and/or customs may need to open your checked bags for inspection. Depending on local regulations they may do this o my in your presence or it may happen behind the scene. If they need to cut open the cling film they won’t be able to put it back and then you end up with two pieces of luggage, neither of which is labelled. Also it may cause all sorts of issues with the automated delivery systems. On the other hand, some airlines actually allow you to split your weight allowance between different bags (hard to determine, usually).

Comment: @jcaron "split your weight allowance between different bags" - I'm not sure this last example refers to the situation described by OP?

Comment: @Sabine for carriers that allow it, it means if you buy a 30 kg allowance you can use it for however many bags you want as long as the total is under 30 kg. It used to be the standard for routes not under the piece concept, it’s a lot less common nowadays.

Comment: Try chatting with Wizzair, asking them directly. https://wizzair.com/en-gb/information-and-services/contact/contact-us look for the "Chat With Us" instructions. And FYI, trash bags are not allowed on commercial flights. Obviously they'd jam the conveyor belts or could split open, dumping your stuff anywhere along the journey.

Comment: @AussieJoe The number of times I have seen people fly with heavy duty trash bags is too many to count (South East Asia especially), so that's definitely not true. Absolutely no idea where your 'obviously' came from. And trying to talk to customer support of low cost airlines is an equally bad idea IMHO (from non-answers to contradictory answers to just plainly incorrect answers, let's just say low cost airlines didn't become low cost by spending a lot on support).

Comment: @DavidMulder I used their chat feature just fine. They said cling film is not allowed.  Last time I checked, WizzAir doesn't operate in SE Asia, so I am unsure your logic here. Good luck.

Comment: How about a large collapsible duffel bag that can fit both pieces inside?